# Create pdf from persian html file by ITextSharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, localization

I use ITextSharp library to convert html to pdf.
My users use persian language sentence in her/his html files, So this library can't convert persian word.

For resolve this and right to left problem i use bellow code:

```
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 80, 50, 30, 65);
        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, new FileStream(strPDFpath, FileMode.Create));
        document.Open();

        ArrayList objects;
        document.NewPage();

        var stream = new StreamReader(strHTMLpath, Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd();
        objects = iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.
        HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StreamReader(strHTMLpath, Encoding.UTF8), styles);            

        BaseFont bf = BaseFont.CreateFont("c:\\windows\\fonts\\Tahoma.ttf",
                                        BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, true);
        for (int k = 0; k < objects.Count; k++)
        {
            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            table.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;

            var els = (IElement)objects[k];
            foreach (Chunk el in els.Chunks)
            {
                #region set persian font
               iTextSharp.text.Font f2 = new iTextSharp.text.Font(bf, el.Font.Size,
                                                el.Font.Style, el.Font.Color);
                el.Font = f2;
                #endregion set persian font

                #region Set right to left for persian words
                PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(10, el.Content, el.Font));
                cell.BorderWidth = 0;
                table.AddCell(cell);
                #endregion Set right to left for persian words
            }
            //document.Add((IElement)objects[k]);                
            document.Add(table);
        }

        document.Close();
        Response.Write(strPDFpath);
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + strPDFpath);
        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
        Response.WriteFile(strPDFpath);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.Close();
        if (File.Exists(strPDFpath))
        {
            File.Delete(strPDFpath);
        }
```

My right to left and convert persian words was resolved, but it have another problem.

**My algorithm can't parse and convert content of table tag that uses in html file.**

Now the question is: How to parse html file that have table tag, div and paragraph tag with persian language sentence, and convert it to pdf?

Comment: "My algorithm can't parse and convert content of table tag that uses in html file." - Mean you that objects doesn't contain tables of original html document or what?

Comment: Hello Kia _Salam aziz ;)_ see this link http://hasheminezhad.com/itextsharp

Answer (score 4):

iTextSharp is able to parse table tags too. but it does not set its RTL properties and you need to fix it yourself:

```
            foreach (var htmlElement in parsedHtmlElements)
            {
                fixRunDirection(htmlElement);
                pdfCell.AddElement(htmlElement);
            }

...

        private static void fixRunDirection(IElement htmlElement)
        {
            if (!(htmlElement is PdfPTable)) return;

            var table = (PdfPTable)htmlElement;
            table.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;

            foreach (var row in table.Rows)
            {
                foreach (var cell in row.GetCells())
                {
                    cell.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL;
                    foreach (var element in cell.CompositeElements)
                    {
                        fixRunDirection(element);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

More info: ([^](http://www.dotnettips.info/Post/615/%D8%AA%D8%A8%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%84-HTML-%D8%A8%D9%87-PDF-%D8%A8%D8%A7-%D8%A7%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%81%D8%A7%D8%AF%D9%87-%D8%A7%D8%B2-%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87%E2%80%8C%DB%8C-iTextSharp))

Answer (score 1):

Try using this
http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

That application reads in a html page and saves it as a pdf. Just run that thing in C# using shell script.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I see that, but i want to use iTextSharp library. Are you have a solution by using iTextSharp library?

Comment: The link is broken.. =(